# Why data from server is not coming in the form of listview?

Tags: android, json, listview

In this code, when i put a text field and show the code over it, then it displays well. But when I want to show the same code using JSON parsing in the form of Listview it didn't appear can anyone tell me the problem.
Check the code...

```
package com.apna.datainlist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.entity.StrictContentLengthStrategy;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Data extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    CustomAdapter cd;
    ArrayList<String> lst=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sublst=new ArrayList<String>();
    TextView tv;
    String Line;
    int z;
    String userRating[];
    String pass[];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new GetData().execute();
//  Collections.addAll(lst, "abc","bc");
//  Collections.addAll(sublst,"pass","v");

    cd=new CustomAdapter(Data.this, lst, sublst);
    lv.setAdapter(cd);
    }
    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {       @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/MyService/Local/abcd.php");
try{
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream is=httpEntity.getContent();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    Line= null;
    while((Line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb.append(Line);
    }
Line=sb.toString();
JSONArray obj=new JSONArray(Line);
z=obj.length();
String userRating=null;
String pass=null;
for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject user=obj.getJSONObject(i);
    userRating=user.getString("username");
    pass=user.getString("pass");
lst.add(userRating);
sublst.add(pass);
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Toast.makeText(Data.this,"Error occurs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
    return null;
}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(Data.this,"Progress",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            tv.setText(z+"ab");

        }   
    }
}
```

data at local server for jSON parsing i.e
at http://localhost/myservice/local/abcd.php

```
 [{"username":"aaa","pass":"sss"},{"username":"aaaa","pass":"sss"},{"username":"abcd 1","pass":"abc"},{"username":"Ankir","pass":"Arora"},{"username":"Ankit","pass":"abcd"},{"username":"Ankita","pass":"abc"},{"username":"avx","pass":"cs"},{"username":"krish","pass":"kuta"},{"username":"sad","pass":"sd"}]
```

Comment: yeah, tried but same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are  getting data from server in async task and immediately after calling async task yor are assigning data to your adapter which is wrong.

Your code:

```
new GetData().execute();
//  Collections.addAll(lst, "abc","bc");
//  Collections.addAll(sublst,"pass","v");

    cd=new CustomAdapter(Data.this, lst, sublst);//you will not get data here...
    lv.setAdapter(cd);
```

make sure that you create your adapter object in post exeute of aysnc task.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
cd=new CustomAdapter(Data.this, lst, sublst);//add this line
    lv.setAdapter(cd);//add this line
            Toast.makeText(Data.this,"Progress",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            tv.setText(z+"ab");

        }
```

Comment: Beacuse  Async task runs in background in thread and your next line code is executed immediately. so your custom adapter will not get data immediately as aysnc task yet not finished. so let the task get finish, then only assign data to your adapter.